# Prevent XSS from external xml files

Tags: javascript, xml, xss

Our front end application takes messages from a trusted third party in the form of xml files. Within one of the elements of the xml record is base64 encoded text that gets displayed on our front end.

I had noticed that some of the decoded text in these messages contained HTML styling elements (i think because our third party users were copying content from a website to paste in to their forms) which, when the record is accessed in the front end, this gets rendered i.e. the text gets displayed in bold etc.

This made me wonder what would happen if I processed a xml file that contained a record with encoded javascript (simple alert script) in the relevant field. Lo and behold when the record is accessed on the front end the javascript executes.

Initially I thought there must be something that can be changed at the front end that will treat the data contained in these xml records as static text so that it would never execute, however the developer has told me that this is not possible due to the fact that the website is using dynamic javascript or webforms or something, I can't really remember what the exact explanation was. They told me that the best way to prevent this is for this to be stopped at the source, however this doesn't seem quite right to me, as although these messages come from a trusted third party, we don't have control over their system and would rely on them making their system secure. So my question is: what is the best way to prevent malicious code being executed at the front end - is there a way for the front end to treat this data as static? Does the answer depend on the platform and type of technology used to develop the web front end?

Thanks.

Comment: To prevent XSS the tool that takes the XML data and converts it to HTML needs to do the work. If that is client-side code then client-side code can do it.

Comment: The best way to stop this is *at the system that renders the content*, not at the source. The system that renders the content must be stable on its own, you can't externalize the trust. So yes, the answer depends on the front end that renders the data. There's always a way of rendering the data without executing it, but the code that does the rendering needs to do that (and you need to find out how it works in order to fix it).

Comment: Great. Thanks for these helpful answers.

Comment: Hi Tomalak, Quentin. The front end is  ASP.net. Initially the dev implemented html encoding on the xml so it was converting < to &lt etc. However this caused the application to throw an unhandled exception "A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client, which is apparently the default ASP.net input validation. The dev then made a change to turn off the html encoding and just strip the angle brackets from the input. This seems to work in that the script is now non-executable. Is a reasonable solution to just extend this to other chars that could form a code snippet?